# Types of elements of a tuple view

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I'm designing a utility to create a *view* into a tuple-like object. The goal is to enable writing code like this:

```
// make_tuple_view<Is...>(t): view of t's elements at positions Is...

auto t = std::make_tuple(42, 'c', 3.14);
auto tv = make_tuple_view<2, 1, 0, 1>(t);  // tv == (3.14, 'c', 42, 3.14)
++std::get<0>(tv);
// tv == (4.14, 'c', 42, 4.14)
// t  == (42, 'c', 4.14)
```

So the element types of a tuple view are appropriate types of references to the corresponding elements in the original tuple. Currently this is how I deduce the reference types:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {

template<std::size_t FromIndex, std::size_t... Is, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto make_tuple_range_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                                     Tuple&& t) noexcept
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(
            std::get<FromIndex + Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}

}  // namespace detail

// make_tuple_range
template<std::size_t FromIndex, std::size_t ToIndex, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto make_tuple_range(Tuple&& t) noexcept
{
    static_assert(FromIndex <= ToIndex,
                  "FromIndex must be less than or equal to ToIndex");

    return detail::make_tuple_range_impl<FromIndex>(
            std::make_index_sequence<ToIndex - FromIndex>(),
            std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

// make_tuple_view
template<std::size_t... Is, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto make_tuple_view(Tuple&& t) noexcept
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}
```

[Tests](https://godbolt.org/g/hE6Vha):

```
double pi = 3.14;
std::tuple<int, double&, const char, float> t(42, pi, 'c', 0);

// non-const lvalue
static_assert(std::is_same<
                  decltype(make_tuple_range<0, 3>(t)),
                  std::tuple<int&, double&, const char&>
              >::value, "");

// const lvalue
const auto& ct = t;
static_assert(std::is_same<
                  decltype(make_tuple_view<3, 0, 2, 1>(ct)),
                  std::tuple<const float&, const int&, const char&, double&>
              >::value, "");

// non-const rvalue
static_assert(std::is_same<
                  decltype(make_tuple_range<1, 4>(std::move(t))),
                  std::tuple<double&, const char&&, float&&>
              >::value, "");

// const rvalue
const auto&& crt = std::move(t);
static_assert(std::is_same<
                  decltype(make_tuple_range<1, 4>(std::move(crt))),
                  std::tuple<double&, const char&, const float&>
              >::value, "");
```

However, I'm not entirely confident in my implementation. Is there any edge case where incorrect reference types can be deduced?

**UPDATE**: Thanks for all the awesome answers, TIL for sure! However, I'm still wondering if my definition of `make_tuple_view/range` can deduce incorrect return types. The purpose of this question is not so much to look for the optimal implementation as to learn about the details of this part of the type system. I'd really appreciate it if more focus can be put on the deduced return type for my `make_tuple_view/range` functions.

Comment: What does having a `std::tuple<char&&>` even mean?

Comment: I think you should enforce the source tuple to be an lvalue if you're creating a view of references to it - otherwise you'll end up with dangling references

Comment: @GuyGreer Imagine `make_tuple_view<...>(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3))`. The `std::make_tuple(...)` part could be the return value of some function.

Comment: @SteveLorimer Imagine `make_tuple_view<...>(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3))`. The `std::make_tuple(...)` part could be the return value of some function.

Comment: @ZizhengTai after `make_tuple_view<...>(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3))` you've got a `tuple_view` of dangling references

Comment: @SteveLorimer Not if that `tuple_view` is immediately passed to a function (ie, is itself temporary)

Comment: @SteveLorimer If you use it like this: `do_something(make_tuple_view<...>(make_tuple(1, 2, 3)))`, then it's fine. It's the programmer's responsibility to not *store* a view to a temporary, I think. It's a view, after all, and not a copy.

Comment: @GuyGreer Yes, exactly my point.

Comment: My worry with the tuple of rvalue references is that trying to use it could destroy the value without expecting it to.

Comment: @GuyGreer Can you give an example?

Answer (score 6):

```
namespace details {
  template<std::size_t...Is,class TupleIn>
  auto tuple_view( std::index_sequence<Is...>, TupleIn&& tin) {
    return std::forward_as_tuple( std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupleIn>(tin))... );
  }
}
template<class TupleIn>
auto tuple_view(TupleIn&& tin) {
  auto indexes = std::make_index_sequence< std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<TupleIn>>{} >;
  return details::tuple_view( indexes, std::forward<TupleIn>(tin) );
}
```

and done?

To move more code to boilerplate:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant< std::size_t, I >;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index{};

template<std::size_t...Is>
auto unpack_indexes( std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  return [](auto&& f) {
    return decltype(f)(f)( index<Is>... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto unpack_indexes( index_t<N> ) {
  return unpack_indexes( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
};

template<class TupleIn>
auto tuple_view(TupleIn&& tin) {
  auto size = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<TupleIn>>{};
  auto indexes = unpack_indexes(size);
  return indexes(
    [&](auto...Is) {
      return std::forward_as_tuple( std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupleIn>(tin))... );
    }
  );
}
```

which does a bunch of (reusable) work to get rid of `details` namespace.

Writing code to manipulate the indexes should be done orthogonally to making the view.

Comment: Wow, didn't know you can use lambda that way!

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution! Can you also take a look at my update?

Comment: I have followed your example to switch to `std::forward_as_tuple`.

Answer (score 3):

Way too complicated. `std::tie` almost does all the work for you.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>


template<class Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
auto tuple_view(Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::tie(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))...);
}

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_tuple(1,2,3);

    auto b = tuple_view(a, std::index_sequence<0,1,2,1,0>());

    std::cout << std::get<0>(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<2>(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<3>(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<4>(b) << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
1
2
3
2
1
```

Comment: I see cppreference describe `std::tie` as: *Creates a tuple of lvalue references to its arguments or instances of `std::ignore`.* Does this mean it can't handle rvalue references?

Comment: @ZizhengTai if you wanted to move, you'd apply it when you invoke `std::get` on the tie.

Comment: Sorry, still haven't wrap my head around. Can you give an example of possible differences between your version and my version when used on temporaries?

Comment: @ZizhengTai when used on a temporary, `t` will be an r-value reference. The tie will successfully decay to a tuple of l-value references to values in the temporary tuple. If you wish, you can move them from there with `std::move(std::get<N>(b))`

Comment: Ah, now I see. So the difference between `std::tie` and `std::forward_as_tuple` (as in my version) is that the former will never return tuples of rvalue references, while the latter can?